# onTapGesture is not working in TabView, how to make it work?

Tags: swiftui, gesture, tabbar

I used the .onTapGesture in TabView but it is not working. It also affecting the tab bar functionality.

```
TabView{
}
.onTapGesture {
            <#code#>
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What isn’t working as expected? What do you expect? I wouldn’t expect this to work because you would be overriding the tab views built in gestures

Comment: I need to change the boolean value using ontapgesture of tabView, So I need the ontapgesture to work in tabView

Comment: It won’t you have to find an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using onTapGesture on tabView we can write an extension to Binding and it will detect the new tab selection value even if we tap the tab bar within the same tab it will detect the changes. Here I am provided the binding extension.

```
extension Binding {
func onUpdate(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
    Binding(get: {
        wrappedValue
    }, set: { newValue in
        wrappedValue = newValue
        closure()
    })
}}
```

I used this in my tabView. I attached my code below.

```
TabView(selection: $tabSelection.onUpdate {
        setNewValue(value: tabSelection)
    }) {
      ContentView()
        .tabItem {
                Label {
                    Text("Home")
                } icon: {
                    Image("HomePage_icon")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                }
            }
            .tag(TabViews.homepage)
}
```

SetNewValue function, this function acts like onTapGesture

```
func setNewValue(value: TabViews){
     self.tabSelection = value
     */ inside this function we can write the code, we like to write it in onTapGesture */
 }
```